# Unexpected directive 'MatAutoCompleteTrigger' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-node

I want to write unit test for closePanel() method.
I have imported MatAutoCompleteTrigger. I am getting the above error please do help me with this.

Comment: you need to provide directive in module

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to the imports in module.
You would have your appModule. You have imported it in the component I guess.
You need to import the **MatAutocompleteModule** in your appModule too.

You would have the array of **imports** add one more entry in that array for **MatAutocompleteModule**.

Now when you import **MatAutoCompleteTrigger** in your file it would work successfully.

Hopefully, you would resolve this error by adding this.

Comment: I tried importing in app.module but I am getting an error saying class MatAutoCompleteTrigger is not an angular module

Comment: I have edited the post accordingly, Please verify it once. I hope this is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

`MatAutoCompleteTrigger` is not a module it's a directive, you can't import neither directive nor component in your module. you have to import a module that declared and exported that directive, in this case it is  `MatAutocompleteModule`. just import only this module and it should be enough